# Bitbucket over http nginx proxy

Tags: http, nginx, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket server that works on a direct IP address very well. But I want to access my bitbucket server using subdomain name and over HTTP, something like bitbucket.subdomain.com

I have found a very good official Atlassian's explanation on how to do it and started from adding new server parameters to the bitbucket.properties

```
server.port=7990
server.secure=true
server.scheme=http
server.proxy-port=80
server.proxy-name=bitbucket.mydomain.com
server.context-path=/
```

everything looks clear to me, so I've decided to change my Nginx configuration and added next server settings

```
#Bitbucket
server {

    server_name bitbucket.mydomain.com;

    # serve static files directly
    #location for bitbucket

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7990;

    }


}
```

the same looks cool for me.

Did all restarts/reload etc and going in my browser to bitbucket.subdomain.com and I see 404

So, I'm really stuck, since I've done a lot of different changes and no, it's not working

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I try the same stuff and this works for me:

Bitbucket.properties:

```
server.port=7990
server.scheme=http
server.proxy-port=80
server.proxy-name=bitbucket.mydomain.com
```

Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bitbucket.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7990/;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
}
```

Then restart both and you are ready to go.

V.